# C Sharp. Протокол обмена IEC60870. Реализация интерфейса IFileSender

Tags: c#, сеть, протоколы

В библиотеке Lib60870 есть метод

```
public override void lib60870.CS104.Connection.SendFile(int ca, 
                                                        int ioa, 
                                                        NameOfFile nof, 
                                                        IFileSender sender, 
                                                        TypeFormat typeFormat)
```

Один из его параметров - класс, расширяющий интерфейс `IFileSender`

```
 public interface IFileSender 
  {
    void Finished(FileErrorCode result);
    void SegmentSended(byte sectionName, int offset, int size, byte[] data);
    byte GetCheckSummData();
    IEnumerable<byte> GetSegment(int size, bool deleteFromSource);
    int FileSize();
  }
```

Как можно реализовать методы?

```
GetCheckSummData();
IEnumerable<byte> GetSegment(int size, bool deleteFromSource);
int FileSize();
```

В *Examples* и *UserGuide* говорится только о реализации `IFileReceiver`, в котором суть методов - вывести в лог информацию из параметров, а в `IFileSender` есть дополнительные.

Comment: По-видимому, надо обращаться в тех.поддержку `MZ Automation GmbH`

Comment: По-моему, вы используете какую-то устаревшую версию библиотеки. Взгляните:
https://github.com/mz-automation/lib60870.NET/blob/3cd1fcec8e51deb9b52364086539f3562c0c4349/lib60870/CS101/FileServices.cs

В этом файле содержится реализация интересующего вас интерфейса, название которого претерпело изменения (теперь это IFileProvider)